# Using PHP to grab words starting with @ in a string

Tags: php

When a user posts a comment, I want to grab every word that starts with a @ symbol.

ex. 
string is 'Check this out @user1. It's a photo of @user2 and @user3.'

When I'm on the PHP side, I want to grab user1, user2, user3 so I can then notify those users that they have been tagged in this comment.

I tried playing with strpos, but closest I got was if the string started with @ using the logic below.

```
if (0 === strpos($string, '@')){ echo 'yes' }
```

but that wasn't what I needed.

Comment: Hi Stephen and welcome to SO. It's normally great to include what you have tried in your question, so that folks answering aren't recreating the wheel - just pointing out where you need an extra spoke in what you have done already. SO isn't really a site where you come to say "Hey, I need a wheel...".

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I didn't mean to come off 'find me a solution'. I just got stuck and couldn't figure this out.

I tried playing with strpos, but closest I got was if the string started with @ using the logic below.

if (0 === strpos($string, '@')){ echo 'yes' }, but that wasn't what I needed.

Comment: You can write a regex that extracts everything that starts with `@` and ends with `(A-Za-z)`, then you'll get an array of usernames.

Comment: I would use explode function to split text to single words and after that I would  verify, if word begins with @ and store them to variable or somewhere.

Comment: You could explode on '@' and check that the beginning of each is non-space, then get the first word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use this function:

```
function get_tagged_users($comment) {
    $matches = array();
    if (preg_match_all('/@(\w+)\b/', $comment, $matches)) {
        return $matches[1];
    }
    return array();
}
```

It will return an array of usernames (without "@") and an empty array if no matches found or if an error occurred while doing regex.

**Note:** It uses regular definition of word boundaries and words. `Lorem @ipsum-ed dolor` will return just `ipsum`.

So if you need to include hypen (-) in usernames, just change regex with `/@([-\w]+)\b/`

Comment: Ok. This works out nicely as well. Like the simplicity of using regexp, but I actually need it to allow '-' in the usernames. I would need that ex above to return 'ipsum-ed' instead of just 'ipsum'. What would I need to add to the regexp to allow '-'?

Comment: Just change regex in function with `'/@([-\w]+)\b/'`. I'll update the answer now

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex method of doing this:

```
$matches = [];
preg_match_all( "/@([-\w]+)\b/",
                "Check this out @user1. It's a photo of @user2 and @user3",
                $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => user1
            [1] => user2
            [2] => user3
        )

)
```

The regular expression matches `@` followed by one or more alphanumeric characters or an underscore (`\w`) up to a word boundary (`\b`). The matched words are in `$matches` (as you may have guessed).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I like how simple this is, but this returns the username with @ in front, how can I get just the username by itself?

Answer (score 0):

A "regex-free" and "explode-free" solution

```
$str = 'Check this out @user1. It\'s a photo of @user2 and @user3.';

$offset = 0;
$users = array();

$str .= ' ';
while($offset = strpos($str, '@', $offset + 1)){
    $users[] = rtrim(substr($str, $offset + 1, strpos($str, ' ', $offset)- $offset), '?.,!:;');
}

print_r($users);
```

However this assumes that your usernames do not contain white space and punctuation characters as well as that a proper white space is present after punctuation.

## EDIT:

I created a quick benchmark script to test which answer was the fastest. Contrary to my belief regex appears to be faster than bit-searching manually. You can see the results yourself [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d901208a67f3e7e5c0870cd651c9670e3299b15c)

Comment: Thank you for your help. What is the main difference between using regex, explode, or your answer?

Comment: @StephenK It **should be** faster because the computer is doing very less work.

Comment: @php_nub_qq Nice! I was going to benchmark it myself but you beat me to it!

Comment: @ialarmedalien I have to admit I'm pretty surprised regular expressions are the fastest solution as everywhere you read people say regex is slow and should be avoided.